# react-hook-form: how to show errors for nested names?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a `register("test.new",{required:true})` in react-hook-form

Now how to show errors of `test.new`

```
{errors.test.new && <p style={{ color: "yellow" }}>This field is required</p>}
```

is not working

Answer (score 1):

Before you enter anything, there is no error, so the `errors` object doesn't have any property, you need to add an [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to safely get the nested property inside in case it's undefined:

```
{errors.test?.new && (
  <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>This field is required</p>
)}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]